# как реализовать динамическое создание компонентов

Tags: c++, qt

В общем у меня есть программа в которой через редактор созданы элементы,
два qTableWidget-a и отдельное окошко с lineEdit- ами. 
И по поставленной задаче я вызываю  отдельное окно, заполняю lineEdit-ы, нажимаю "Ок",  после чего в одном из qTableWidget появляется строка с  **динамически созданном компонентом "qCheckBox-ом"**.

Как это сделать (именно динамический элемент) ??

Answer (score 0):

Лучший ответ это пример.

Создаём приложение QtWidgets.

Накидываем в .ui для удобства сократил до кнопки и одного qTableWidget-а.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прописываем в коде динамический элемент.

Для начала объявляем в заголовочном файле в основном классе QCheckBox (.h).
После вызываем его в реализации, при нажатии кнопок (.срр).

*--- Вот код ----*

**.pro**

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2018-06-13T14:38:41
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = test11
TEMPLATE = app

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any feature of Qt which has been marked as deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
# deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0


SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
        mainwindow.h

FORMS += \
        mainwindow.ui
```

**mainwindows.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    // Создаём виджет, который будет содержать в себе чекбокс
    QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget();
    QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    QHBoxLayout *layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindows.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    //-- добавляем чек бокс в таблицу
    checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); // создаём новый qwidget()
    checkBox = new QCheckBox();      // объявляем и инициализируем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox = new QHBoxLayout(checkBoxWidget); // создаём слой с привязкой к виджету

    checkBox->setText(QString::number(666));
    layoutCheckBox->addWidget(checkBox);            // Устанавливаем чекбокс в слой
    //    checkBox->set
    layoutCheckBox->setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);  // Отцентровываем чекбокс
    layoutCheckBox->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);    // Устанавливаем нулевые отступы

    ui->tW_test->insertRow(ui->tW_test->rowCount());//вводим колич строк (возвращ колич строк)
    ui->tW_test->setCellWidget(ui->tW_test->rowCount()-1, 1,  checkBoxWidget); // добавляем элемент в таблицу (строка, столбец, добавляемый элемент)
}
```

**mainwindows.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>727</width>
    <height>450</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <widget class="QTableWidget" name="tW_test">
      <property name="rowCount">
       <number>0</number>
      </property>
      <property name="columnCount">
       <number>3</number>
      </property>
      <column/>
      <column/>
      <column/>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>PushButton</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>727</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

И вот результат.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Установите `parent` для каждого созданного элемента, дабы он самоликвидировался вместе с `MainWindow` или `QTableWidget`. `ui` должен уничтожаться в самую последнюю очередь, не забывайте что он лежит в окне.

Comment: @LLENN простите но код выдаёт мне `  /release/test11.exe завершился с кодом 0 ` и это при множественном нажатии на кнопку. Он и так перент ибо он в приватах .

Comment: `checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); checkBox = new QCheckBox();` Не наблюдается. Вы затираете указатели, не уничтожая объекты.

Comment: @LLENN ` D:\kononov\Projects\test11\mainwindow.cpp:20: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QCheckBox::QCheckBox(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     checkBox = new QCheckBox(parent);      // РѕР±СЉСЏРІР»СЏРµРј Рё РёРЅРёС†РёР°Р»РёР·РёСЂСѓРµРј С‡РµРєР±РѕРєСЃ
                                    ^ `

Comment: @LLENN `D:\kononov\Projects\test11\mainwindow.cpp:19: ошибка: no matching function for call to 'QWidget::QWidget(<unresolved overloaded function type>)'
     checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(parent); // СЃРѕР·РґР°С‘Рј РЅРѕРІС‹Р№ qwidget()
                                        ^`  Ух починил наконец :3 Не то что было раньше когда всё работало и не выдавало ошибок )))

Comment: Пожалуйста, люди которые разбираются в памяти приведите в виде кода куда и где и что я должен вставить, я не понимаю. Спасибо.

Comment: Я вам еще раз напишу, у вас у классе объявлено 2 указателя, которые вы затираете нажимая на кнопку: `QWidget *checkBoxWidget = new QWidget(); QCheckBox *checkBox = new QCheckBox();`

Comment: `MainWindow::~MainWindow() { delete ui; delete checkBoxWidget; delete checkBox; delete layoutCheckBox; } `но почему то ошибку" некорректное завершение программы " винда выводит, работаю в Qt5.10.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78822/discussion-between-llenn-and-timob256).